# Implicit conversion to an Objective-C pointer using SQLite3

Tags: ios, objective-c

I following old tutorial that use MRC, and when i pasted code i got an error:  `Implicit conversion to an Objective-C pointer using SQLite3` on a line:

```
if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
```

Full code snippet is :

```
static FailedBankDatabase *_database;

+ (FailedBankDatabase*)database {
    if (_database == nil) {
        _database = [[FailedBankDatabase alloc] init];
    }
    return _database;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banklist"
                                                             ofType:@"sqlite3"];

        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Im not very keen in MRC, can you help me fix it?

Comment: Using SQLite APIs directly is generally a waste of time.  There are reasons to go there, but they are rare and advanced cases.   I'd suggest using `CoreData` or `FMDB`.

Comment: @bbum thank you for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_database` variable is your static reference to the `FailedBankDatabase` singleton. But you are also trying to use it to save the SQLite database reference. For that, you need an instance variable of type `sqlite3 *`.

Update your code to something like the following:

```
@implementation FailedBankDatabase {
    sqlite3 *_db;
}

+ (FailedBankDatabase*)database {
    static FailedBankDatabase *database = nil;

    if (database == nil) {
        database = [[FailedBankDatabase alloc] init];
    }
    return database;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banklist"
                                                             ofType:@"sqlite3"];

        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_db) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now use the `_db` variable for all database references in the various `sqlite3_...` function calls.

FYI - you should use a more modern approach to creating the singleton:

```
+ (FailedBankDatabase*)database {
    static FailedBankDatabase *database = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;

    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        database = [[FailedBankDatabase alloc] init];
    });

    return database;
}
```